# I am looking forward to match two images using some fast method

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am looking forward to match two images with some fast method. I have two data-sets and want to find same images and save them separate or save it's name or index

I have tried to convert image into a vector and subtract them, then count total number of non-zeros in vector. but this technique is not working fine sometimes

```
    name_orb = strcat(ORBSLAM, char(Name_orb(i)));
    img_orb = imread(name_orb);
    gray_orb = rgb2gray(img_orb);
    gray_orb = gray_orb(:);
    %% reading orb images (key frames)
    name_key = strcat(Key, char(Name_key(k)));
    img_key = imread(name_key);
    img_key = img_key(:);

    %% difference between vectors
    vec_diff = gray_orb - img_key;
    %vec_diffe = img_key - gray_orb;
    %% finding non zero entries in difference 
    nnz_diff(i-1) = nnz(~vec_diff);
```

Comment: `But this technique is not working fine sometimes` Show two example images that can be tested. Tell us why you feel these 2 images are matching when computer says they are "not matching". If we understand what exactly you're looking for in the pixels, then we can advise you better.

Comment: Here is link of images , here Keyframe1 is the image that I want to find from the other images. It is not giving error, it returns wrong image index in end 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LkBfu-rbeUAaACeNd4juXVoPer-TODET?usp=sharing

Comment: two images are matching on basis of number of non zeros in vector difference, I don't why it is coming high in case of some other image , which is not matching with that image. I want to compare two images and see if they are same or not !!

Comment: Have you tried to [cross-correlate](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html) the images?

Comment: no , I have not tried cross-corerlation technique, can you kindly guide me to use it !! Also tell me it would be fast or not ? @PatrickHappel